# Cross platform KVM over ethernet

Tags: kvm-switch

I'm not sure if this exists, but this is what I'd like to do. I have a laptop and a desktop that I work on about equally. The laptop runs windows 7 and the desktop is on kubuntu 10.04. What I want to be able to do is be able to drag my mouse accross my screen and have it act like my laptop is a second monitor. Whereby I can use my desktop mouse, drag it say to the left off of my desktop monitor, and use it on my laptop (I don't care about the keyboard, just the mouse). Is that possible? Are there any other solutions that exist? I'd prefer not to have a physical kvm switch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like Synergy is what you are looking for? http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about that. I think I remember hearing about that a long time ago. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: That's what I use between Windows XP and a Red Hat Enterprise Linux system (with the server on the Linux side) and it works great. The latest is here: `http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/`.

Comment: I also used it for years, mainly between WindowsXP (the client machine) and a Mandriva Linux (as the main machine). There was even an architectural difference, Linux@64bits and Windows@32bits. It was working almost perfectly, however sometimes the Windows machine's synergy process died silently, but a restart of the process always fixed the problem. This was not a big problem, happened only on once or twice a day.

Comment: There's only linux packages for 1.3.4 but there's no list of changes between the versions. Should I compile 1.3.5 from source so I can use the same version on Windows/Linux or does it not matter?

Comment: Running 1.3.4 on my linux server with a win7-x64 client running 1.3.5. Working great so far

Comment: Used this for a long time on Windows XP SP3 and CentOS 5.{0-3}.

Answer (score 0):

**[Input Director](http://inputdirector.com/)** is less buggy than Synergy and works better between Windows-only systems.

> Input Director is a Windows application that lets you control multiple Windows systems using the keyboard/mouse attached to one computer. It is designed for folks who have two (or more) computers next to each other and find themselves regularly switching from one system to the other. With Input Director, you can share a single keyboard/mouse across a set of systems. You switch which system receives the input either by hotkey or by moving the cursor so that it transitions from one screen to the other (in a very similar fashion to a multi-monitor setup). The idea being that you can position the monitors from two or more systems in a row and use a shared keyboard/mouse to control all of them.